# RegEx find newline between double quotes and replace with space

Tags: javascript, regex

I need help to replace a newline with space in a string with double quotes and value between.

This is my current expression but it's only replace newline if string doesn't contain any other value.

```
/"([\r\n]*?)"/g
```

I want to change this:

- "Log field with multiple lines.

  This is now fixed."

For this:

- "Log field with multiple lines. This is now fixed."

Comment: Can the substrings in between `"` contain escaped literal `"` chars? Can there be multiple line breaks in between the quotation marks?

Comment: For now, no. I collect data from csv file and then search for place where is unwanted newline between double quotes.

Comment: Doesn't that mean that literal `"` are represented with `""`? It is important to know how to detect the open and close "s between which you want to remove line breaks.

Comment: Try `s.replace(/"(?:""|[^"])+"/g, function(x) { return x.replace(/[\r\n]+/g, ' ');})`, see [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/htc91e5w/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a function within `.replace()` like this:

```js
var data = `
I need help to replace a newline with space in a string with double quotes and value between.

This is my current expression but it's only replace newline if string doesn't contain any other value.

I want to change this:

    "Log field with multiple lines.

    This is now fixed."

For this:

    "Log field with multiple lines. This is now fixed."
`;

var regex = /"[^"]*"/g;

data = data.replace(regex, function (match, capture) { 
    return match.replace(/[\n\r]\s*/g, " ");
}); 
console.log(data);
```

First, it looks for anything bewteen dobule quotes, second is removes newlines and possible consecutive whitespaces thereafter. The approach won't work with escaped quotes though.

Comment: @AleksanderKarp: Glad to help. Consider upvoting the other answers as well if they helped you.

Comment: @AleksanderKarp FYI: 1) If you match `""`, there is no text in between and thus nothing to replace, hence `/"[^"]+"/g` makes more sense than `/"[^"]*"/g`. 2) `/[\n\r]\s*/g` is meant to only "shrink" spaces after a linebreak char. To shrink all of them on both sides, use `/[^\S\r\n]*[\n\r]\s*/g`. I [updated my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53777149/3832970).

Answer (score 3):

To remove all chunks of line break chars in between double quotation marks, you need to match these substrings between the qualifying start and end double quotation marks. Thus, it is crucial to know if `"` chars can appear escaped in between the `"` delimiters.

In a CSV, the literal double quotation marks are usually doubled. Then, you may use

```js
var s = '"Cell1","Cell\r\n#2","""Cell #3\r\nhere\nand there"""';
s = s.replace(/"(?:""|[^"])+"/g, function(x) { return x.replace(/[^\S\r\n]*[\n\r]\s*/g, ' ');});
console.log(s);
```

The `"(?:""|[^"])+"/g` regex matches a `"`, then 1 or more occurrences of `""` substring or any char other than `"`, and then `"`. When the match is found, all CR and LF symbols with any 0+ whitespaces before and after them are removed using a simple `.replace(/[^\S\r\n]*[\n\r]\s*/g, ' ')` replace operation.

If the literal double quotation marks are escaped with a backslash, you may use

```
/"[^"\\]*(?:\\[\s\S][^"\\]*)*"/g
```

If you are sure there are no escaped double quotation marks, use

```
/"[^"]+"/g
```

Comment: Great answer and elegant solution. I just used this to produce  Go solution for a question on Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/xr6glj/i_need_to_unmarshal_a_json_object_which_contains/iqg36uw/

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your problem:

```
/\r\n|\r|\n/g
```

**1st Alternative \r\n**

\r matches a carriage return (ASCII 13)
\n matches a line-feed (newline) character (ASCII 10)

**2nd Alternative \r**

\r matches a carriage return (ASCII 13)

**3rd Alternative \n**

\n matches a line-feed (newline) character (ASCII 10)

**g modifier**

All matches (don't return after first match)

Comment: Use a character class with a quantifier like `[\n\r]+`, your alternation is very ineffective.